# Como redireccionar a una url en una pestaña nueva en JSF?

Tags: java, web, jsf, redirección

tengo una aplicación web hecha con Java JSF y necesito que al tocar un botón me abra una pestaña nueva hacia un página externa a mi aplicación.
La página a redireccionar no es .faces

Comment: Hola... y como es que tienes tu código?

Comment: Por el momento no tengo código porque intenté con FacesUtils.redirect("www.youtube.com"), como ejemplo, pero no encuentra la página porque le agrega .faces al final.
Además no me abre una pestaña nueva.

Comment: tal vez esta pregunta te pueda sacar de dudas... [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955130/jsf-page-redirecting-from-java-bean)